# ionic2 + angular2 - disable button on click

Tags: ionic-framework, angular, ionic2, ionic-view

I have list of rows, and each one row has 2 more more buttons. I want to disable button on click event, so once its done ajax call then I can reenable it or hide it completely.

So I'm wondering how can I disable this single button on click event.

how can I disable from event?

```
<button [disabled]="buttonDisabled" (click)="trigger($event)">

trigger ($event)
{
  $event.buttonDisabled = true; // ?
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<div *ngfor="#row of rows">
  <button [disabled]="awaitingAjaxCall[row] ? true : null" (click)="trigger($event, row)">
</div>
```

```
rows: [0,1,2];
awaitingAjaxCall:boolean[] = [false, false, false];
trigger ($event, row)
{
  this.awaitingAjaxCall[row] = true;  
  this.http.get(...).map(...).subscribe(value => {
    this.value = value;
    // or here
    // this.awaitingAjaxCall[row] = false;
  }, error => {},
  () => this.awaitingAjaxCall[row] = false);
}
```

Comment: Your question only has one button. What are the other buttons? Which one(s) do you want to enable/disable?

Comment: on my question it says. I have list of rows and each row has 2 or more botton.   each button is clickable (after click, it needs to be disabled until ajax call)

Comment: All buttons of the row where a button was clicked?

Comment: I don't know how to answer your question if you can't make it more clear what you want. Could you add a few buttons, name them A, B, C, .... and explain which button is clicked and which buttons should be disabled because of this click an why.

Comment: Do you mean only the button that was actually clicked should be disabled?

Comment: Yes. only the actual button which is clicked should be disabled.

Comment: Then it's quite similar to my current answer. I used an id for all buttons of a row. Just change it to use a different id for each button. You can assing it statically `<button (click)="trigger($event, 0)`>b0</button><button (click)="trigger($event, 1)`>b1</button>` or dynamically like I did in my answer. This depends on how you create your buttons which is also not obvious from your question.

Comment: it has to be from model variable? can't it be from event... like we use to do in jQuery.

Comment: It don't "has to be" but that's IMHO the Angular way. You can also do `$event.target.enabled = false` ... `$event.target.enabled = true` but you should avoid accessing the DOM imperatively. This might break when you want to use server side rendering or WebWorkers.

Comment: I have tried with `$event.target.enabled = false` that did not work at all.

Comment: Sorry, my bad :-( There is no `enabled` should be `disabled`. https://plnkr.co/edit/hLCeBl?p=preview

Comment: unfortunately it does not work on ionic2, maybe its a bug on there side. not sure.

Comment: How does it "not work"? Any error?. It's so basic I can not imagine why this shouldn't work if other things are working.

Comment: No not any error at all. It just stays enabled. I think it has more handler in the background that might have side effect...